# Accordion panel customisation based on user's input

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, accordion

I am using accordion widget in a questionnaire (400 questions), where every panel represents question and content - response area. Since there is long row of questions, a user would like to have a visual aid of what questions have been responded. This is achieved by altering background colour of accordion panel.

***(Please see example here - in CHAPTER 4 http://jsfiddle.net/PatrickObrian/b3A7a/31/)***

Each question can have 4 options to respond: Yes, No, NS and NA. For "N" response - accordion panel should change the background colour to "A", otherwise it should change it to "B". If no response is given = should remain default.
Now, simple as it looks, I am trying to play with inline css option in and yet still have not been able to make it work))))

```
jQuery(function () {
  $('.Response').change(function () { 
   if (this.value == 'Y') { 
    $('.ui-accordion-header').css("background-color", "green"); 
   } else if (this.value == 'N') { 
    $('.ui-accordion-header').css("background-color", "red"); 
   } 
   }); 
});
```

So the problems I am having atm are:

1 - it does not work as of yet; and

2 - class "ui.accordion-header" applies to all accordion panels in the long row of questions (abt 400); thus when "Y" is selected it changes background of ALL accordion panels in the questionnaire, whereas it should change only of that specific question, where user provided response.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('.Response input[type=radio]').change(function () {
        console.log(this.value)
        if (this.value == 'Y') {
            $(this).closest('.ui-accordion-content').prev().css("background", "green"); 
        } else if (this.value == 'N') {
            $(this).closest('.ui-accordion-content').prev().css("background", "red"); 
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.ui-accordion-content').prev().css("background", ""); 
        }
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sabof/R4sHj/

Comment: Sorry, it does not(((((

Comment: There was some css interference. I've changed `background-color` to `background`. You should see it working now.

Comment: Oh, yeah. You should also change `.Response` to `.Response input[type=radio]` http://jsfiddle.net/sabof/R4sHj/3/

Comment: YES IT DOES! THANK YOU dearly!

Comment: I've added an example of how to erase the styles, if that's what you wanted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48377/discussion-between-alexander-and-sabof)

Comment: No need. Try: `this.value == 'Y' || this.value == 'NA' || this.value == 'NS`